# Magento 2. Use same email templates for emails sent from admin and frontend without duplicating the templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates

- I have multiple custom emails that are triggered by events either from admin or from frontend.
- I would like to use the same email templates without duplicating the email template files or configuration from etc/email_templates.xml.
- I tried putting the emails in view/base/email it does not work.

If additional info is require please ask. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Keep template at `view/frontend/email.html` and try to send custom mail from admin.

Comment: It will result in an empty email with empty subject